# PowerBi Service principals and Row level Security

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, row-level-security

We are using PowerBi and would like to embed a report in another system.
We have set up everything so far and can display the reports with a service principal for several users.
However, we only want the users to see their own records, so we have created roles that only display a few records based on the username. This works well in the PowerBi Desktop 'view as'. But when we request the embed token from the other system, we get a 400 response code back.
I have read the following(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls):

> Service principals cannot be added to an RLS role. Accordingly, RLS won’t be applied for apps using a service principal as the final effective identity.

Can I then achieve my goal at all, that a large group of users can view a report and only see their own data? Or is that only possible if I create a separate account for each user?

My report without roles can be embedded. That works.
Then I added a role to my report. Role is Owner and DAX is [Owner__c] = USERNAME()
[image]

And adjusted the body of the API from:

```
{
"accessLevel": "View",
"datasetId": "8d72284e-f104-4213-9376-606397b2f838"
}
```

to

```
{
"accessLevel": "View",
"allowSaveAs": "false",
"identities": [{
    "username": "0015p00005ZSE7wAAH",
    "reports": ["7fa1badb-ccb3-45b8-84cb-15e5b2018efa"],
    "roles": ["Owner"],
    "datasets": ["8d72284e-f104-4213-9376-606397b2f838"]
}]
```

}

This is a my datatable [image]

Did I miss a point?
Do I need to add someone(who?) to this the role under dataset security?

Why is USERPRINCIPALNAME() or USERNAME() not the id, which I defined in the request body?
As soon as I add a role to my report(Dax:[Owner__c] = TRUE) or ([Owner__c] = USERNAME() or even hardcoded [Owner__c]='0015p00005ZSE7wAAH') I get a status code 400

Comment: What is '0015p00005ZSE7wAAH'?  If you create a measure `CurrentUser = USERPRINCIPALNAME()` in your model, what does it show when you embed the report?  When embedding only the Master User or Service Principal needs any DataSet privileges.

Comment: '0015p00005ZSE7wAAH' is an external id from the system in which I want to embed the report. This id is listed in the report and I would like to filter by it. If I install the measure and remove the role permissions from the report, I get a long value as current user 7a107ae5-1cc9-4402-ac45-0c5eadb6df62

Comment: Why is USERPRINCIPALNAME() or USERNAME() not the id, which I defined in the request body?

Comment: As soon as I add a role to my report(Dax:[Owner__c] = TRUE) I get a status code 400

Comment: And the workspace is on a premium capacity?

Comment: Does that really have anything to do with it? I can display the report embedded if I have not defined any roles.

Comment: The workspace License is 'Pro'

Comment: I have looked at the licence model and Embed APIs and controls are included under the PRO version: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/
There is also no indication in the documentation that further licences are required: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-row-level-security#adding-roles-with-power-bi-desktop

Comment: Users require a Power BI Pro license to access reports deployed in a Pro workspace.  The only way to embed without a capacity A, EM, or P,  is to have the users authenticate themselves to Power BI, and then the users must have Power BI Pro lcenses. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-your-organization?tabs=net-core

Comment: In the article 'Embed content for customers' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=net-core I now also see the Note: 'To move to production you'll need a capacity.' When does Production apply? As soon as I use RLS?

Comment: I don't know what parts of the scenario are technically blocked on pro workspaces, and which work-but-aren't-supported.  In general you'll need a PPU workspace, or a capacity to do this.  You can get started with a small Azure Power BI Embedded A capacity, that you can pause when not in use. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/power-bi-embedded/#overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the Content-Type => application/json it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The Service Prinicpal is not the "effective identity".  The Service Principal generates the embed token, and the embed token specifies the effective identity of the user, which can be an arbitrary string that you use in your RLS filters.

> With Row Level Security (RLS), you can choose to use a different
> identity than the identity of the service principal or master user
> you're generating the token with. Using this option, you can display
> embedded information according to the user you're targeting. For
> example, in your application you can ask users to sign in, and then
> display a report that only contains sales information if the signed in
> user is a sales employee.

[Generate Embed Token - Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/generate-embed-token#row-level-security)

See also
[Row-level security with Power BI Embedded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-row-level-security)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but then I'll have to ask what I'm doing wrong. I have edited my post.